# Create an "int" column forced between 0 and 3

Tags: update, sqlite, constraint

I would like to create a table with one column that would be of type "integer", and locked between 0 and 3. Is this possible?

My goal would be to have this column so that I could just execute a increment or decrement command, to increment or decrement the value in the database.

#### Example

If value in DB = 0
I execute something like `UPDATE xxx SET yyy = yyy-- WHERE zzz`
Value would still be 0

If value in DB = 3
I execute something like `UPDATE xxx SET yyy=yyy++ WHERE zzz`
Value would still be 3

If value in DB = 3
I execute something like `UPDATE xxx SET yyy=yyy-- WHERE zzz`
Value would still be 2

If value in DB = 1
I execute something like `UPDATE xxx SET yyy=yyy-- WHERE zzz`
Value would still be 0

Comment: Triggers will allow you to examine values before they are written to the table and adjust so your bounds are honoured. A constraint will throw an error if a value outside the bounds is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers. I am using SQLite3 local on my laptop for testing purpose, I am not sure what the "real" database will be.
So for that reason and because it does not seem easy to restrict values in a certain range, I have solved my problem in the software itself.

Using the "AND" condition to check if values are in the interval I want: "UPDATE xxx SET xxx WHERE xx ***AND*** xx"

Thank you all.

Comment: It's very easy to restrict values. Use a `check` constraint: `CHECK (column BETWEEN 0 AND 3)`